# How to work with multiple form in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have 2 forms. 
one is the main one and the other is the secondary. 
the first one contain a datagrid with displays the columns of a sql table.
the second has textbox of the sql table of the first form and a save button.

when a run the first one from the design mode to the execution mode it's display the form with the datagrid in executive mode.
but when a run the second form from the design mode to the executive mode so that i can enter data, it gives me the first form(datagridform).

which c# code can i use so that when i want to enter data from the second it can do it? because when i execute the second form from the design mode to executive mode i end up on the firstform so it is difficult for me to enter data from the second form.

if there is a misunderstanding of the question plz let me know.

i need your ideas guys.
thnx.

Comment: `textbox of the sql table of the first form` is not clear. You must open Form2 from the click event of the datagrid, passing it the value to be edited and the primary key of the row if you wish to write the value back to the database.

Comment: Looks like you think that, when you hit the debug button in the IDE, then you get the form you are currently looking at in the designer. It doesn't work like that. The debug button starts your application always with your application's default form. You have to write code to bring up a second form.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the first form because that's the form in your application start. Look for a line like this:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

in a file called `Program.cs`.

You need to **launch the second form from the first one**. So, you could add a button to the first form and put this code in its `Click` event:

```
var f = new Form2();
f.Show();
```

where `Form2` is the name of the second form.

Also consider this, you may want to use `ShowDialog` when showing the second form. That's up to you. Try it both ways and see.

Answer (score 1):

Give your Form1 a Button with the Event you see below to open the Form2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form2 form2 = new Form2();
  form2.Show(); // form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create object of second Form.

Form1 frm = new Form1();

Call `ShowDialog()`  or `Show()` as you need. If you need to pass any data then use common property as member.